# Web2py and Sencha

Tags: extjs, web2py

I'm new to Web2py and Sencha, and I would like to see a simple example using both frameworks. I have googled but I haven't found anything.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got everything working. To ensure that the js  files are rendered it is necessary to paste them in the static folder of the web2py project. With Sencha Architect I have created a project in the mentioned location, so for example to call the controller from the js view an Ext.Ajax.request is made:

```
 onDataRender: function(component, eOpts) {
     Ext.Ajax.request
     ({
        url: '/r/rec/getdata',
        method: 'GET',   
        params: '',      
        success: function(response)
        {

            o=Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            component.setSource(o);        
            console.log(response.responseText);

        },
        failure: function(response)
        {
            component.setSource({"Error" : "No data"});     
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }

      });
 },
```

The controller then gets the resquested data from database, generates a json and returns it to the view layer:

```
  def getdata():
       jsondata="{"
       data=db.song.find()
       for s in data:
           jsondata+="\""+str(s["_id"])+"\" : \""+str(s["name"]).replace("\"","")+"\"," 
       return jsondata[:-1]+"}"
```

The getdata method gets all the data (it is a test example), to get a specific record the id can be passed as a parameter with request.args(0).